# Using the DataView in XPages Extension Library Mobile Controls

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib

On page 1 of a mobile app I need to display categories from a categorised view. When the user selects a category the app should transition to page 2 showing documents in the selected category. The customer does not want the category to expand/collapse on the first page of the app.

Would I use the DataView for this? Any advice on how best to achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if something like this http://sutol.mapsys.cz/ (application is in Czech, but you can still see what it is about) is what you need, I can send you the code.
"dopoledne" and "odpoledne" are categories

Comment: one xe:appPage reads the first column of the categorized view to construct the top level list. Second xe:appPage contains view restricted to that selected category. I think selected category is sent via requestScope variable. I can look to the app...

Comment: An example of the xsp code for page 1 would be useful if possible. Thx

Comment: I am at some stupid meeting so I can't reach the Designer client now, but it basically is a repeat over first Categorized column of a view: `view1.getColumnValues(0)` (with `var="cols"`) and inside the repeat there is Static Line Item with label value of `cols`

Comment: on man, this hurts! I've just check the code and it really is repeat over categorized column values but there are two more `xe:appPage`s containing the view with hardcoded attribute pageName. I was probably too lazy to do it right:( Sorry if this leads to nowhere...

Answer (score 0):

Yes what you want is a dataview, there is a property to disable collapsing / expanding of the category sections.

My suggestion would be to view either of the remodelled templates "Discussion 853 XL" or "Teamroom 853 XL" that come with the ExtLib, these applications have been modified to add mobile front ends and are great examples of how to build mobile applications

Answer (score 0):

I do something along these lines in mobile pages of XPages Help Application - Contents and Index views both drill down from categories to documents in the category. I think I just use a repeat control.

The one thing to bear in mind is that you cannot currently redirect to the current Mobile Page with different parameters. That's why I switch between two mobile pages that use the same Custom Control for the view.

Comment: Hi paul, that issue with needing multiple mobile pages sounds like a bug i fixed in the lastest ExtLib on openNTF, you should give it a try.